# How do I enforce one assertion per Unit Test at compile time

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I'd like to enforce, at compile time, the usage of a single assertion in JUnit tests
What is the best way and which tool is best?

If there are tests with multiple assertions I'd like to fail the compilation or the build

Comment: You cannot because java compiler wont check for that.

Comment: nor should you. You would have to write dozens of unit tests where one would (should) suffice

Comment: Tests may call helper methods which call helper methods which use `if (somerandomsnumber>0) assert(stuff)` No compiler will dig down there to guess whether something is an assert that you don't want to see there. You could try to provide some insight what you really want to achieve, which problem you think is solved with your request, and you might get answers that do not require the "single assertion" condition.